# Eloquent JavaScript Chapter 6 Ineratior interface example, "this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y)"

Tags: javascript

It is another post about Eloquent JavaScript Chapter 6-Ineratior interface. I have read other post about this book example but I didn't find any discussion on  "value: this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y)"

I don't understand the ".get(this.x, this.y) ", what does this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y) do?. I can't find any related information about the .get. I can only find the get() method of Map object which returns a specified element from a Map object. But in this case, this.matrix is not a map object.

the complete book example

```
class Matrix {
  constructor(width, height, element = (x, y) => undefined) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.content = [];

    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        this.content[y * width + x] = element(x, y);
      }
    }
  }

  get(x, y) {
    return this.content[y * this.width + x];
  }
  set(x, y, value) {
    this.content[y * this.width + x] = value;
  }
}
class MatrixIterator {
  constructor(matrix) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.matrix = matrix;
  }

  next() {
    if (this.y == this.matrix.height) return {done: true};

    let value = {x: this.x,
                 y: this.y,
                 value: this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y)}; //the problem is here
    this.x++;
    if (this.x == this.matrix.width) {
      this.x = 0;
      this.y++;
    }
    return {value, done: false};
  }
}
Matrix.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  return new MatrixIterator(this);
};
let matrix = new Matrix(2, 2, (x, y) => `value ${x},${y}`);
for (let {x, y, value} of matrix) {
  console.log(x, y, value);
}
// → 0 0 value 0,0
// → 1 0 value 1,0
// → 0 1 value 0,1
// → 1 1 value 1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized the .get refers to the

```
get(x, y) {
    return this.content[y * this.width + x];
  }
```

Sometime you really need to take a break if you are learning coding.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently studying that part and what I got to understand is this:

```
value: this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y)
```

Here, get() refers to the get property defined in Matrix class:

```
    get(x, y) {
    return this.content[y * this.width + x];
    }
```

and what it does is return the value stored at (x, y) for Matrix object passed to the iterator.